# How to get all pages from facebook account

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I have tried to get all facebook pages list. But I got an error.

Error is :  request is not defined

Code :

```
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts';
var accessToken = req.user.facebookAccessToken;
    var params = {
        access_token: accessToken,
    };
    request.get({  url: url, qs: params}, function(err, resp, pages) {
       // console.log(resp);
        pages = JSON.parse(pages);

    })
```

Comment: save your token into req.session.facebookAccessToken instead of req.user

Comment: This is not a problem for access Token. I have checked it before.

Comment: Use Javascript SDK of fb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting isn't related to Facebook.

"request is not defined" means you're trying to do something with the variable **request** (call its **.get()** function in this case) but the variable **request** hasn't been set anywhere.

Your tags indicate this is in Node. Do you have this line already?

```
var request = require('request');
```

If not, add that before the code in your question. That loads the 'request' module you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

You got the issue on request ,,

install npm request

```
require('request').get({
    uri: url,
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
   body: require('querystring').stringify(params)
}, function (err, resp, body) {


})
```